# Fastest way to compute covariance on vectors that are cutting through a 3D image stack. Ideas?

Tags: arrays, image, opencv, image-processing, numpy

I've got a bunch of grayscale images (represented as matrices) stacked on top of each other.
In fact, I've got two copies of these same images, because I want to calculate the covariance of pixel intensity between individual pixels in one frame and pixels to their right in the next frame. I'm writing this with NumPy and OpenCV. I want to store the covariance values in a matrix with the dimensions of one frame of the stack (the width will decrease by one).

The image stacks are represented as (3D) arrays with dimensions HxWxL.

Should I just go through each coordinate and use np.cov(first_vector,second_vector)[0,1] and map that covariance value to a new matrix hundreds of thousands of times?

I bet there's a faster way. When I use the NumPy covariance function, I get an error saying my objects were not aligned. That makes sense because I'm passing a 3D array as arguments. I just don't know how to pass a 1D array efficiently. Any ideas? Here is my code:

```
def covar(self):
    stack1 = self.zstack()
    stack2 = self.zstack()

    cur = np.delete(stack1,0,1) #remove first column
    cur = np.delete(cur,-1,2) #last frame
    ahead = np.delete(stack2,-1,1) #remove last column
    ahead = np.delete(ahead,0,2)
    return np.cov(cur,ahead) #<-Error because not 1D/2D array. I know I /could/ write as np.cov(cur[0,0],ahead[0,0]) but that is slow...
```

Thanks for any help :D

Comment: If anyone is familiar with SciPy Multi-dimensional image processing (scipy.ndimage), I could use some advice. That looks like it might be the key.